# SSH to a server and have session running with all commands executed to have them saved in local file

Tags: python, perl, shell, ssh

I basically want to SSH to a server and then the commands executed in a server and its outputs be saved into a local file. I thought below one would save the output to a file but is exiting once commands are executed *i can understand its done with its execution so its exiting but i do not wish to exit unless i exit from the server

1. SSH to server via script
2. Save the output of all execution in server in local file
3. Come out , if exit found

**Here is the basic code:**

#! /usr/bin/bash

ssh user@server > file.log << EOF

pwd;hostname;

EOF

Comment: Linux (and many other *nixen) include a utility called `script` that may be of use here...

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to save the output of an interactive SSH session, do this:

```
ssh userid@server | tee logfile
```

Your example implies that you want to run some commands (pwd, hostname) from your shell script, and then keep the ssh connection open for interactive use.  I'd suggest instead adding those commands to your login script on the server (.profile or whatever.)

If you **really** want to use your method, take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103885/piping-data-to-a-processs-stdin-without-causing-eof-afterward

Comment: This post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86941/how-to-ssh-into-a-specific-directory also might be helpful - you could exec a shell as the last command in your list.

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for.. Thanks @ewindes